# Calculate Median with filter in sql

Tags: sql, filter

my query looks something like this:

```
select 
column1,
column2,
column3, 
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5 ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Integer_column  )  OVER (PARTITION BY column1,column2) as MEdian_Integer_column 

from Table
```

I want to exclude when Integer_column = 0. I have tried with something like `FILTER (where Integer_column

 <> 0)` , but I do not know to write correctly (syntax errors). Could someone help here?

Comment: What database do you use ? MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server... ? Do you have some example data you can share with us ??

Comment: One more thing:  "(syntax errors)" show us the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using Oracle as your database but I can not be sure. If you do here is the code you can use:

```
select column1
       , column2
       , column3
       , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5 ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Integer_column  )  OVER (PARTITION BY column1,column2) as MEdian_Integer_column 
from MyTable
where Integer_column <> 0;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f5264a9a241da69571a88d2ff798d4ad)